# Mysqli(or PDO) and PHP to Javascritpt array through JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli, pdo

I have researched this question thoroughly. I know there are similar posts but there is simply something wrong with the code. I am fetching all rows from my database through PHP/PDO script (have also tried the similiar MYSQLI version). I then use json_encode to send the results back to the javascript/jquery.

What ever it is, i can send any other type of data through the json and print it through the javascript. But I can't seem to get the array stored in $arr stored in the javascript allArray.

I have tried JSON.parse(allArray) with no luck.

**getAllData.php**

```
   <?php 

header('Content-Type: application/json;');

$a = "bob";
$b = "george";
$arr = [];


/* Connect to a MySQL database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=guessthe_bob;host=localhost';
$user = 'guessthe';
$password = '***';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id,title FROM questions2 ORDER BY id");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
//print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
$arr = $result;

echo json_encode($arr); 

// Free result set
$sth = null;
$dbh = null;

?>
```

**.js**

```
    $.getJSON("functions/getAllData.php", function(data) {

     var allArray = data;

        $.each(allArray, function(index, value){

        $('.testSpot').append(index + ": " + value + '<br>');

    });
```

}

null

Comment: Could you also post the JSON that you are having trouble with as well.

Comment: If your PHP has issues, `$.getJSON` will fail, in which case nothing happens (because you aren't reacting to an error). You need to test the PHP code first, and once you've made sure you're getting proper JSON, that's when you move on to AJAX. Or you check the Network section of your browser's dev tools. Just navigate to `http://localhost/site/functions/getAllData.php` in your browser for now.

Comment: The php does work and if i use print_r($results) the array will print.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by print the JSON? i have no specifical file as i use just the two scripts of json above.

Comment: he means print json instead of $result. Because you are expecting json, $results. Do what you expect, that's easy

Comment: had you verified your ajax is completing and you are getting the json.[You can use chrome developer tools' and inspect on the network tab]

Comment: Yes - If i switch the verable to $a on my php file it will out put

Comment: Yes - If i switch the verable to $a on my php file it will out put - 0: b
1: o
2: b